# I'm being asked to create IN queries for different GUIDs...huh?

Tags: sql, uniqueidentifier

I'm a GIS intern.

I've been asked:

"Could you also create IN queries for the different sets of GUID’s? Here is an example:
"GlobalID" IN '{58BEE03F-1656-4BD5-B53D-B887E93A5287}', '{009C7364-8D77-46B3-A531-B60ED4E5B407}', '{0105263C-1305-4AB9-A00A-4BED01832177}')"

I'm not sure what that means or why I'd have to do it. What I can tell you is that I have several .shp that I have geocoded and then created global IDs for. 
I've googled this for hours now and am no closer to understanding the request than I was. It could be that the answer is staring me in the face but I don't think I know enough to know that.

Thank you,
Kathy

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding what an `IN` query is? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create and understand `IN` queries, first you'll have to understand the basics of a query. It sounds like this might not be something you're familiar with, so I'll start with that.
There are 3 main parts to a query, `SELECT`, `FROM`, and `WHERE`.

`SELECT` is the information (or columns) you want to return. You can `SELECT *` to select all columns or `SELECT specificColumn1, specificColumn2` to select specific columns.

The next step is the `FROM` statement. From determines what table(s) you will be querying. You can query multiple tables here if you like and tables can also be aliased like so: `FROM table1 t1`.

The third statement is the `WHERE` statement, which specifies any conditions that the query is required to meet. In your case, this is where your `IN` statement will go. There are a ton of different keywords you can use here, but I'll just give a quick sample query for you (keep in mind I have no idea what your schema looks like).

```
SELECT *

FROM GUIDData

WHERE GlobalID IN ('{58BEE03F-1656-4BD5-B53D-B887E93A5287}', '{009C7364-8D77-46B3-A531-B60ED4E5B407}', '{0105263C-1305-4AB9-A00A-4BED01832177}');
```

So what this query will do, is it will give you all the data for each item in the `GUIDData` table with a global ID of `{58BEE03F-1656-4BD5-B53D-B887E93A5287}`, `{009C7364-8D77-46B3-A531-B60ED4E5B407}`, or `{0105263C-1305-4AB9-A00A-4BED01832177}`.

Did this help?